# The app references non-public selectors in Payload/<Appname>.app/<App name>: birthday

Tags: ios, validation, warnings, submission

I have created an iOS app that has third party library FacebookSDK.framework and FBUserSettingsViewResources.bundle (this is extracted from facebook-ios-sdk-3.9.pkg). The app runs fine on Simulator and Device.

But when I created Archive and did Validate step I got an error. I searched the internet and stackoverflow questions and all referred to 'id' and not 'birthday' as selector & provided solutions.

"The app references non-public selectors in Payload/.app/: birthday"

From my own code I removed all usage of 'birthday' as selector. But I still got the Validation error.

I have submitted the app for review with app and status shown in Organizer is "Submitted with Validation Warnings". Not sure if Apple will approve the app or not.

Can anyone please provide me with some guidance on this.

Comment: Get the SDK source code, replace all `birthday` selectors with appropriate key-value operations, build SDK, use it.

Comment: Did your app got rejected by apple?

Answer (score 3):

instead of sending selector birthday: and id: use NSDictionary objectForKey:@"id" or objectForKey:@"birthday"

br
Calin